# How to append country code in two different input fields using javacscript and jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I just try with these two fields two append country code separably but somehow if I try to do with one input field it will affect also second input field. so how can it work for two separate fields?

```
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="contact1">SMS No.</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="smsno" id="smsno" placeholder="Type contact1 number here...." pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required />
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="contact2">WhatsApp No.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whtspno" id="whtspno" placeholder="Type contact2 number here...." pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required />
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'adminpanel/src/build/js/intlTelInput.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
          'use strict';
          window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
              form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
              }, false);
            });
          }, false);
        })();



        const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#smsno");
        const phoneInputField2 = document.querySelector("#whtspno");
        const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
          
        });
        const phoneInput2 = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField2, {
          
        }); 



        $(document).ready(function() {
          
          
          $('.iti__flag-container').click(function() { 
           
            var countryCode = $('.iti__selected-flag').attr('title');
            var countryCode = countryCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
            $('#smsno').val("");
            $('#smsno').val("+"+countryCode+" "+ $('#smsno').val());
            
         });
        
      });


        /*function country_code(){
          var val = document.getElementById("country").value;
          
          if (val === "select country"){
            document.getElementById("smsno").value = "";
          }
          else if(val === "us"){
            document.getElementById("smsno").value = "+1";
          }
          else if(val === "In"){
            document.getElementById("smsno").value = "+91";
          }
        }  */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasroquilly/pen/yLvEMjM) with your code : country code are appended to the input when a flag is clicked, and it works for the two separate fields.

I used the classes `smsForm` and `whatsappForm` on the .form-group elements so I can use these classes as a selector in the js code to identify which flag of which field is clicked. Could also have used `:eq(0)` and `:eq(1)` selectors.

```js
const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#smsno");
const phoneInputField2 = document.querySelector("#whtspno");
const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {});
const phoneInput2 = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField2, {}); 
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  });
}, false);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.smsForm .iti__flag-container').click(function() { 
    var countryCode = $('.smsForm .iti__selected-flag').attr('title');
    var countryCode = countryCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    $('#smsno').val("");
    $('#smsno').val("+"+countryCode+" "+ $('#smsno').val());
  });
  $('.whatsappForm .iti__flag-container').click(function() {
    var countryCode = $('.whatsappForm .iti__selected-flag').attr('title');
    var countryCode = countryCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    $('#whtspno').val("");
    $('#whtspno').val("+"+countryCode+" "+ $('#whtspno').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.17/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.17/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6 smsForm">
        <label for="contact1">SMS No.</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="smsno" id="smsno" placeholder="Type contact1 number here...." pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required />
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 whatsappForm">
        <label for="contact2">WhatsApp No.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whtspno" id="whtspno" placeholder="Type contact2 number here...." pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required />
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls use code snippets.

Comment: @ArchitGargi done - sorry, I'm just starting to answer questions on here